# API frameworks for node.js

Tags: api, node.js, frameworks

Which API frameworks for node js best suits mobile applications (native or HTML5) or client-side HTML5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there are many frameworks (https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-web-frameworks-full) , like restify, express, I think hapi was built for your needs. Its focus is on your business logic, and favours configuration for simple and fast deployment.

You can find the package in https://npmjs.org/package/hapi, and https://github.com/spumko/hapi

It looks very promising. There's a talk about the framework in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Recv7vR8ZlA where the main contributor talks about what makes an API framework tick.

It supports caching, validations, plug-ins and more (watch the video).